# How to convert std::array to std::tuple?

Tags: c++, arrays, tuples

I am working on a aux module to pass values between polymorphic objects and at some point I have

```
std::array<void*, N>
```

and need to send forward

```
std::tuple<void*, void*, /* N times */>
```

I can figure some solution with the use of `index_sequence` or/and recursions, but all of those look bulky and difficult to read.
Is there any more straightforward way to do this by the means of the standard library?

Also, just in case - am I right that the layout of `std::array` is a dense set of respective objects, thus equal to, lets say, `void**` of respective length, whereas the layout of tuple allows gaps?

Comment: Not actually a duplicate. The former question is about more specific problem and for some reason has no satisfying answer (so asking it again anyway was useful).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your implementation supports it (optional pre-c++23, but now mandatory), you can use [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat). It concatenates any number of objects that respect the tuple interface (which `std::array` does) into a single flat tuple. Concatenating a single tuple like object will just produce a tuple that holds copies of the members of said source "tuple".

```
std::array<void*, N> a;
auto b = std::tuple_cat(a);
```

> Also, just in case - am I right that the layout of `std::array` is a dense set of respective objects, thus equal to, lets say, `void**` of respective length, whereas the layout of tuple allows gaps?

A `std::array` is an aggregate that will hold a `void*[N]` internally. So yes, the elements will be without padding in between them. The layout of the tuple's elements is not specified to such an extent.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for...

Comment: you're an `std::tuple_dog`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken - Said the `std::tuple_chicken`!

Comment: I was looking for this myself but cppreference mentioned that it only concatenates tuples. Never thought that std::array was usable as well (though the example shows a std::make_pair case)

Comment: @gast128 Yeah, but, from the other end: ["An array can also be used as a tuple of N elements of the same type."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: @gast128 - Usually, anything that goes by `std::get<i>(...)` can work for a `std::array` as well. There are overloads and type traits for it that are meant to make it behave like a tuple.